# Propagation of uncertainty in a derivative of a function

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, error-propagation, derivative

I've performed an ordinary least squares on a data set with one variable. For simplicity, let's say I've fitted a polynomial function
$$f(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3.$$
I obtain the best fit and the standard error (via the covariance matrix) for each of the fit parameters. Now, I want to calculate the error in $f'(x)=\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ at a particular value of $x$.

How should I go about doing this? I've taken a look at [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86366/propagation-of-uncertainty-when-integrating-or-differentiating) post, but I don't quite understand how to apply it to $f'(x)$.